# RewrittenPath Class is missing in monox

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, content-management-system

I hope to build a social network website through monox. I downloaded monoX_5_1_40_5107. When I compiled monox project in visual studio, there are errors of missing RewrittenPath class. I searched the keyword "RewrittenPath" in the entire project, I can't find any definition about it. But when I like to continue and run the last successful build, the website runs well, I can create import the database into local database, and even can create new account info through website.

the  compilation erorrs is as below: :
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'RewrittenPath' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\MonoX\T4Templates\RewrittenPaths.cs   27  13  WebApplication1

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking for? It seems like you're having problems, but yet it's working? If you're seeking help with the compilation errors, please edit your question and include the output from the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version monoX_5_1_40_5150 was just released,and the problem is fixed in this version.So just update project with the latest version.